# Migrate Appcelerator App to React Native maintain SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, react-native, appcelerator

Not really "migrating" our app per se, but actually we are building a new version from scratch using React Native.
We will be using the same BundleID etc etc so that this update just installs over the top of the last app.

What we would like to do though, is have access to the SQLite database that existed in the Appcelerator project.

From reading a few articles it seems like it should be possible, however everytime I connect my new app to the simulator or use and Ad Hoc build to update from the previous version, it seems that the database is empty.

**database.js**

```
import SQLite from 'react-native-sqlite-storage';
SQLite.DEBUG(true);
SQLite.enablePromise(true);

export default class DbTest {
  static listTables(callback) {
    const errorCB = err => {
      console.log('SQL Error: ' + err);
    };

    return SQLite.openDatabase({name: '_alloy_'}, callback, errorCB);
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
  saveToState(db) {
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql('select * from sqlite_master', [], (_, results) => {
        console.log('Query completed', results);

        this.setState(previousState => ({results}));

        // Get rows with Web SQL Database spec compliance.
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    DbTest.listTables(this.saveToState);
  }
```

If I log out what results has in it I get

```
 LOG  Query completed {"insertId": undefined, "rows": {"item": [Function item], "length": 0, "raw": [Function raw]}, "rowsAffected": 0}
 LOG  SQLite.backgroundExecuteSqlBatch({"dbargs":{"dbname":"_alloy_"},"executes":[{"qid":1111,"sql":"COMMIT","params":[]}]})
 LOG  SQLite.backgroundExecuteSqlBatch({"dbargs":{"dbname":"_alloy_"},"executes":[{"qid":1111,"sql":"BEGIN","params":[]},{"qid":1111,"sql":"select * from sqlite_master","params":[]}]})
```

If anyone has any experience or can point me to an article I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the database has data inside? Existing DB needs to be linked and then *tell* `react-native-sqlite-storage` where to find it and open it.

Comment: @ChristosLytras I am sure that the database has data inside, when the appcelerator app is installed. What do you mean by "linked" ? That might be something I am missing.

Comment: You need to add the SQLite database file to your project and then use `createFromLocation` property when you open the database `SQLite.openDatabase({ name : "testDB", createFromLocation : "/data/mydbfile.sqlite"})`. See [`Importing a pre-populated database`](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage#importing-a-pre-populated-database) section.

Answer (score 0):

Run your Appcelerator app in the simulator or on a device. Then go grab the "*alloy*" database using Finder and put it into your React project. I open and query the database created when I install my apps on a simulator all the time using DB Browser for SQLite.

Comment: I can understand this if we had a database which was the same for each user out there, like reference data or something. But this database has saved preferences etc with each users database containing unique data. Are we saying it is impossible to access this now? Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to have two apps on same phone? One in React accessing the Appcelerator database?

Comment: No, new React Native app. Using the same name and bundleID as the old Appcelerator project. New version number. Hopefully users will just auto update and get the new app to replace the old one. Trying to access the SQLite database that was being using by the old Appcelerator project but have access to the data that the user has saved in it from the new version of the app (which will be built with React Native).

So it might be that Appcelerator is not saving the SQLite db file in the standard location, so when I try to access it in RN it is not found. I will look into this

Comment: Now I see what you're trying to do! I would love to see you solve this. 
A couple of ideas you can try.

a) Make sure you run your old app on simulator first and work with some data. The first time you add data to the Alloy model, the database file is created named _alloy_.sql and the table and record are added.

b) Changing the React openDatabase file name to "_alloy_.sql"


c) Add the database "location" parameter to your React openDatabase call. Use "Library" or "Documents". 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sqlite-storage#opening-a-database